# Set of points in $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $z^{n-1} = \overline z$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I think I've reached a solution for the above question, I'd like to know if my answer makes sense, and my process follows the appropriate steps, I'm rather new to working in the complex space.

Let $z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. Then:

$z^{n-1} = \overline z$

$z^n = z\overline z$, where $\overline z = r(\cos\theta - i\sin\theta)$. Then for $z\overline z = r^2(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)(\cos\theta - i\sin\theta) = r^2$, thus we get:

$z^n = r^2$

$r^n(\cos n \theta + i\sin n\theta)  = r^2 \implies r^{n-2}(\cos n \theta + i\sin n\theta) = 1$. This gives us the set:

$\{z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) : r^{n-2}(\cos n \theta + i\sin n\theta) = 1\}$

Continuing as mentioned in the comments we can solve for $r$ and $\theta$. Rewriting we get (from here let $cis\theta = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$):

$r^{n-2}cisn\theta = 1cis0.$ Clearly, $r^{n-2} = 1$ and since $r \geq 0$ then $r = 1$ for $n \geq 3$. And then:

$n\theta = 0 + 2\pi k, k = 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots n-1$

So $\theta  = \frac{2\pi k}{n}, k = 0, 1, 2, \dots n -1 $. This gives us the set:

$\{z = cis\theta : \theta = \frac{2\pi k}{n}, k = 0, 1, 2, \dots n -1, n \geq 3\}$

Comment: What you have is correct, but there is a lot more you can do from there. You can actually find what values of $r$ and $\theta$ satisfy that equation. Try writing it as $r^{n-2} e^{in \theta} = 1$ and use that the left side must be real

Comment: I tried to solve for $r, \theta$ but keeping it in polar form. I think this also works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly reframed the equation as $z = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$, and indeed we have
$$
r^{n-2}(\cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta) = 1
$$
But we can say a bit more.  Note that the polar form of a complex number is *unique*, so in particular, we have
$$
r^{n-2}(\cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta) = (1)(\cos 0 + i \sin 0)
$$
this means that $r^{n-2} = 1$, and $n \theta$ is a multiple of $2 \pi$.

Because $r$ is a non-negative number, we necessarily have $r^{n-2} = 1 \implies r = 1$ (as long as $n \geq 3$).

Noting that $n \theta$ must be a multiple of $2 \pi$, we deduce that the possible values of $\theta$ are
$$
\theta = 0,2\pi/n,4\pi/n,\dots,(n-1)2\pi/n
$$
While we could list additional values of $\theta$, any other values would lead to the same polar form as one of the values above.

So, the possible solutions are $z = r [\cos \theta + i \sin \theta]$ where $r = 1$ and $\theta$ is one of the values listed above.  At least, this is the solution when $n \geq 3$ is an integer.

Comment: Haha I just did this exact calculation as you were writing it! Although I did forget to add the restraint on $n$! So thank you, and I'm glad I extended the solution correctly.